# Disabling Dialog Flashing C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I have a populated ListView dialog.  If a user clicks on an option in the ListView, a new dialog is shown above the ListView.

My problems is that when I click off of the new top-most dialog (onto the ListView behind it), the new dialog's borders flash/blink several times.  The icon on the taskbar also flashes.  I wish to disable the flashing, but cannot find a property to change.

To show my dialog, I use the following code:

```
    if (detail == null)
            detail = new Details(opt, val, user, desc, m_l);
        else
            detail = null;
        detail.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: What technology are you using? `WebForms`, `WinForms`, `WPF`?

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms

Comment: how is the dialog created? like, `Form f = new Form();` maybe?

Comment: detail = new Details(opt, val, user, desc, m_l); detail.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like to me you are creating modal windows each time.  And you cannot resume the previous dialogs until you dismiss your new top-most window.

Take a look at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) for information about modal dialogs.

I would advise you look at how you are creating/showing your windows.
In WPF you show windows via `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`, however, I do not know which type of `ListView` you are using

**EDIT:**
Per your comment, you want modal dialogs.  The only ways I can think of even trying to remove the flashing is going into WINAPI.  This doesn't seem like a job for .NET.

I want to suggest a few things:

- Take a look at options for showing each window.  [See this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Take a look at the options for styling each window. [See this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Reconsider your design.  I know this may take a lot of work, but having so many layers of windows is kind of unappealing to most users.  Ultimately, I believe this option will make your application the best.

Comment: I would like my program to do what it is doing.  I wish for the user to be unable to resume the previous dialogs until they dismiss the new top-most window.  However, the blinking 6-7 times it unnecessary and I would like it to blink once or not at all.  The problem occurs if the user double clicks on an option in the ListView (instead of single click), the new dialog flashes 6 times right away.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson I've updated my answer to give you some suggestions.  It seems to me you do in fact desire modal dialogs and just want to remove the flashing effect.

Comment: Thank you Nick.  I will follow your suggestions and post back if I find anything.  As far as a new design, I only have two dialogs showing.  One is the listview and the second allows you to edit the listview by changing the selected option.

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior, it's because the new dialog is [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). It's drawing attention to the fact that something needs to be done.

If you need to make a non-modal form, instead of using `ShowDialog()`, simply use `Show()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am creating a new form.  
            detail = new Details(opt, val, user, desc, m_l);
            detail.ShowDialog();

Comment: yup, I edited my answer to show you how to create your Details form as a non-modal form. `ShowDialog()` is used to request a response from the user.

Comment: I do wish to request a response from the user.  So I suppose ShowDialog() would be correct for what I am doing.  My ListView shows a list of options for a separate application.  When the user clicks on an option, a new dialog is show.  The user then fills in a new value for the option and clicks on a button to change the new value in SQL server.

Comment: It depends on your specific requirements... If your user is required to respond before doing anything else, then use a modal dialog. This is a common use case, since you don't want them to enter a new value to submit if the backing data isn't the same as when they originally clicked your ListView. Based on what you've said I would agree, you DO want a modal dialog. If necessary you could add some text that explains that they need to close it before doing anything else, but I think most users would understand that from the flashing.

Comment: Thanks. So what I have gathered is my code is correct.  However my original question still hasn't been answered.  Although it may make sense for it to flash.  My employer asks that it be removed.  It is very easy to click on an option one-too-many times and have the window flash like crazy.  I should have given better background information when asking my question.

Comment: I would advise against that. I understand your employers point of view, but the point is your UI is locked while that dialog is open; you want to draw attention to it. Like Nick says below, you have to do some serious coding to change this behaviour, it's a property of Windows, not your specific form. Maybe you could have your users double-click initially instead of single-click.If you remove the flashing and your UI is locked with no indication as to why, you'll have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and guidance.  I have found the best way to handle my problem.

I was using an event ItemActivated.  This event was called when an a highlighted item on the ListView was clicked.  This became a problem when the user would double click on an already selected item.  This would cause the new dialog to show, but also flash several times.

By using the DoubleClick event instead, a single click on a selected object does nothing.  A double click on either a selected or non-selected item opens the dialog without the flashes.  The flashes still appear if you try to click off of the dialog box, but are not as much of an issue.